# На "стЕнах" или "на стенАх"?

Tags: фонетика

Почему в слове стены (мн. ч.) при склонении ударение переходит на другой слог: на стенАх, хотя мне всегда хочется сказать: на стЕнах?

Answer (score 5):

Ударение на А в предложном падеже этого слова  используется только в определённых сочетаниях, а именно: ***в стенАх чего-либо и в четырёх стенАх.*** 
В целом парадигма ударений в слове выглядит так:
СтенА - стенЫ, стенЕ, стЕну, стенОй, о стенЕ. Но: зА стену, нА стену; как Об стену горох;
***МН***. стЕны, стЕн, стЕнам и стенАм, стЕнами и стенАми, о стЕнах. Но: ***в стенАх чего-либо и в четырёх стенАх.*** (Т.Ф. Иванова. Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка. М.: Рус.яз. - Медиа; Дрофа, 2008, стр.752)
Получается,  что говорите Вы правильно: ***на стЕнах***, а смещать ударение на А вы можете только в оговоренных случаях.

Comment: Все верно, кроме, имхо, последней фразы. 
Татьяна Федоровна,возможно, подходжит уж со слишком жесткой меркой, применимой разве что для для дикторов.
В живой речи - это не "в определенных сочетаниях", это более старый вариант склонения (по Зализняку). [Аванесов][1] дает его как допустимый, 
Зализняк - вторым возможным.  

[1]: http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0560.htm

Comment: Просто словарь Ивановой вышел лет на 20 позже словаря Аванесова. Уважаемого Рубена Ивановича не стало еще в 1982 году.

Comment: Андрей Анатольевич здравствует, дай ему Бог творчекого долголетия!  
А двадцать лет - не срок. Тут не в том дело. Иванова все-таки автор словаря для дикторов. У нее вообще нет понятия "допустимый вариант".

Comment: Андрей Анатольевич - это Зализняк? Аванесова у нас в ДВГУ преподаватели очень  уважали (некоторые из Москвы были) и называли его только по имени  - отчеству. а вот Зализняка я не помню, только фамилию.

Comment: А двадцать лет как раз срок. Разрешили и фольгУ, и ржавЕть и др.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, оба варианта - на стенАх и на стЕнах допустимы и равноправны.

Во-вторых, на вопросы с "почему" обычно невозможно ответить. Ответ на "почему" требует указания причины и следствия, а такие вещи в языке проследить очень сложно, если они вообще существуют. Так сложилось, это живой язык и он живет по своим правилам.

Могу только сказать, что в русском языке ударение вообще подвижное и часто переносится с корня на флексию и обратно.

Answer (score 1):

Это словоформа типа 5, где ударение в существительном единственного числа с окончания перемещается на основу существительного в винительном падеже. Во множественном числе схема перемещения ударения неустойчива: в одних словах ударение перемещается, как в четвертом типе, в других – остается на основе.
 Примеры: бородА, боронА, головА, горА, душА, землЯ, зимА, порА, рекА, спинА, средА, стенА, сторонА, ценА, щекА.
И в этой группе существительных нередки колебания ударений: вОдам – водАм, вОдах – водАх, дУшам – душАм, дУшами – душАми, рЕкам – рекАм, рЕками – рекАми, стЕнам – стенАм,о стЕнах-о стенАх, но: в стенАх (жить в четырёх стенАх).

Comment: Простите, по какой системе "типа 5"? 
По Зализняку: 1d'-1f.

Comment: Я говорю о 6 типах подвижного ударения в существительных,данных в учебнике для студентов и старшеклассников группы авторов(«Нормы русского литературного языка: учебное пособие»)и Словаре лингвистических терминов Т.В. Жеребило.

Comment: Не всегда "в стенАх". Например, "остались пули в стЕнах".